# how to import google-font with vitejs?

Tags: vite, google-fonts

Troubles with google-font & vitejs

I would like to know how to import google-font (or other fonts) for my Vite project, despite Vite has already all config in index.html for css, scss, sass, etc.., but there is nothing about how to configure Vite for google-font. Please, help me. (My config = Vite -> React -> TypeScript -> sass).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I used the google fonts' provided `<link>` until I found **[FontSource](https://fontsource.org/)**.

It allows to **import google fonts via npm**. Since then, it became my standard for every project because of the DX and its **[benefits](https://fontsource.org/docs/introduction)**.
https://fontsource.org/docs/getting-started

This solution also happens to be adopted in the Astro framework, powered by vite.
https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/fonts/#using-fontsource

Hope it helps,
**GdS**.

Comment: Yes, Fontsource is great. It's all I use now.

Comment: Nice! First time I've heard of this site (FontSource). Bookmarked!

Answer (score 1):

So, you can import the url in your css file(s), it´s so simple:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=__CHOSEN_FONT__);

body{
  font-family: '__CHOSEN_FONT__', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it will cause either delayed loading, or likely a FOUT (Flash of unstyled text) as the font loads and is swapped out. Better to preload the font.